# Как изменить URL без перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript

есть страница с одной статьей
Выглядит URL по типу site.ru/news_one
Прокручивая страницу у меня грузится новые статьи , события загрузки я получил, а так же при загрузке я получаю новый url статьи. Итого при загрузке новой статьи у меня в переменной newURL выводится site.ru/news_two. Вопрос лишь в том как изменить url вверху, на новый, без перезагрузки без ничего. Просто что бы менялся URL.

Comment: window.history.pushState(null, null, '/news_two');